# throw an exception with custom statuscode

Tags: c#, .net, exception, throw

Can I change the `StatusCode` in a `catch(System.Exception)`?

```
try
        {
            var result = await _query.GetAllAsync<PersonDto>(nameof(Person));
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw Exceptions.UnprocessableEntity();
            }
            
            return new Response<List<PersonDto>>

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
```

Comment: Hmm, what is StatusCode...  Should this question have been tagged with [asp.net]?

Comment: Its HTTPS Codes. 200, 400, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If its http status codes you are looking for the following example can help.

```
public IActionResult AddNewSample()
    {
        try
        {
            //Does work
            return Ok(); //Status200OK
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message); //Status400BadRequest

            //return StatusCode(500); choosing a different status code
        }
    }
```

The following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) can help to return the appropriate status codes

I hope this helps but it would be useful if you update your question to include more information.